# Can't make new fields in object if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I currently have this code that get information from an API and uses gathered information and write it to a JSON file.

```
var xp;
fs.readFile('./xp.json', 'utf8', (err, data ) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    xp = JSON.parse(data);
});

console.log(m['id'] + " " + m['channel_id'] + " " + m['username']);

var usr = m['id'];
if (!xp[usr])
    xp[usr] = {xpp: 0};
xp[usr].xpp++;
fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
});
```

When I run this I get this error message: 
[Error MSG image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3PGa.png)

So I guess the problem is with the `if (!xp[usr]) xp[usr] = {xpp: 0};`

My intentions with that line is:

```
if it's no field in the json object called usr
...
make a field looking like this:
string of usr = {
   xpp = 0
}
```

I have been stuck on this one for some hours now. Any suggestions?

full function:

```
    var infoUrl = "https:widget.json";
function giveXP(xyz) {
  console.log("Interval Started");
  request(xyz, function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
      var memberz = parsedData['members'];
      memberz.forEach(function(m){
        if(m['channel_id']){
          var xp;
          fs.readFile('./xp.json', 'utf8', (err, data ) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            xp = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(m['id'] + " " + m['channel_id'] + " " + m['username']);
            var usr = m['id'];
            if (!xp[usr]) xp[usr] = {xpp: 0};
            xp[usr].xpp++;
          });
          fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
} setInterval(giveXP, 3000, infoUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to access xp[usr] once the fs.read gives you result. as its async you have to put your code in its callback. please take a look of below code

```
  var xp;
  fs.readFile('./xp.json', 'utf8', (err, data ) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    xp = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(m['id'] + " " + m['channel_id'] + " " + m['username']);
    var usr = m['id'];
    if (!xp[usr]) xp[usr] = {xpp: 0};
    xp[usr].xpp++;
  });

  fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
  });
  // ...
```

Comment: i added current code to the description of the post. still doesnt work.

Comment: are you getting content from xp.json in data of fs.readFile()?

Comment: oh, it looks like im not getting anything. The write works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `xp` indeed doesn't exist at that time due to the fact that `readFile` is asynchronous.
So you need to move you logic in the callback:

```
fs.readFile('./xp.json', 'utf8', (err, data ) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  xp = JSON.parse(data);

  if (!xp[usr]) {
    xp[usr] = {xpp: 0};
  }
  xp[usr].xpp++;
  fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
  });
});
```